# Merge project subfolder and another project

Tags: git, merge

Suppose I have a large git project containing many submodules. Now, suppose I have another git project that is just a modified version of one of these submodules. How would I go about merging my big project's submodule with the lone submodule repository? The history of the lone submodule repository need not be preserved.

For example, suppose I have a project
with the following structure:

```
project/
    subproject1/
    subproject2/
    ...
```

and another git project that is just a modified version of `subproject2/`, say `subproject2-mod/` (note that this repository is essentially a "subrepository" of the big repository. After merging `project/` and `subproject2-mod/`, the result should be as follows:

```
project/
    subproject1/
    subproject2merged/
    ...
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `subproject2` and `subproject2-mod`? Do they share a common ancestor commit? Also, do you need to keep the current version of `subproject2` for e.g. use in other projects?

Comment: No, they do not contain a common ancestor commit. The current version of subproject2 need not be saved.